# uninstall solana completely from Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I installed solana cli on my Ubuntu 20.04 to work as validator node. I am a beginner and I made some mistakes along the way and the validator did not start.
I used the command :

`sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.9.12/install)"`

Now, I want to start all over again from scratch and for that I want to know that deleting the folder 'solana' is enough or do I have to take some more steps?

Comment: Hello. What was the EXACT command you used to install it? This info is needed to tell you how to remove it. Do not at this point just delete a directory.

Comment: @David that is the exact command. See here https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find out the solana installation folder running:

`which solana`

usually it's `~/.local/share/solana` and remove it
and also remove `~/.config/solana`